# TouchActions does not work when using AndroidDrive

Tags: c#, android, selenium, appium

I'm trying to use `MoveToElement` method as part of the TouchActions class (C#).
Seems I have a problem while using it with `AndroidDriver`.
I have a Native App and I'm trying to run it on Android device(Note 5)

```js
 TouchActions MoveTo = new TouchActions(_driver);
 MoveTo.MoveToElement(NameOfElement);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```html
System.ArgumentException : The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasTouchScreen.
Parameter name: driver
```

Comment: what is the `_driver` in use a instance of?

Comment: AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>

Comment: Did you got answer for this as i am also facing the same issue ?